# Undefined method `<<` in image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

```
def create
    @product = Product.find(1)
    @product.images << params[:image]
    @product.save
end
```

The schema is

```
 t.string   "images",       default: [],              array: true
```

I want the assign the image coming in params to the images array, if the image is already there. The new image should append, otherwise it should be the first one

Here is the Product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader  :images, ProductUploader

    validates :name, presence: true 
    validates :price, presence: true
    validates :availability, presence: true
    validates :about, presence: true
    validates :ref, presence: true
    validates :texture, presence: true
    validates :shipping, presence: true
    validates :category, presence: true
    validates :notes, presence: true

end
```

I generated the ProductUploader through carrierwave uploader command

```
class ProductUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_whitelist
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

After uploading the image, the image shows up in params. But does not get saved in the table. Here is the screenshot of byebug

[image]

Edit:

I have made some progress

I updated the string [] to json for images like this

And instead of files coming like string, it's coming as file. Now the only problem is, I am unable to access the name properly `name=\"image[avatar_1]\"` in the params

```
"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JbtcVdUvPJIzSHycX0wdr349zcATDN51vSewI33nvHIKQdhxxgxWUEJz9ZsubNrgvq2ftO+DosHXWM8Tipce7w==", "image"=>{"avatar_1"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f2ba8377f78 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160704-20497-1czlw3s.png>, @original_filename="no-save.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[avatar_1]\"; filename=\"no-save.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"submit", "controller"=>"upload", "action"=>"create"}
```

Here is the view file

```
<%= simple_form_for :image, method: :post, url: save_image_path do |f| %>

        <%= f.file_field :avatar_1 %>

        <%= f.submit :submit %>

    <% end %>
```

here it is avatar_1. I need to change it in create code, but I am not accessing params itself properly

Comment: Which database engine are you using? How does the error look like? Also, for arrays, you should use `text` instead of `string`.

Comment: `params[:image]` contains a `String`, instead of a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`. You should probably add the [multipart form data](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) to your form. And, again. which database engine are you using? Postgresql? MySql? And finally, you should check [this](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Add-more-files-and-remove-single-file-when-using-default-multiple-file-uploads-feature).

Comment: @Wikiti please have a look at the edit. I have made some progress based o n your inputs, I am using postgres

Comment: You can access the filename by using `params[:image].original_filename`. If you need to rename the file, then define the `filename` method on your CarrierWave handler (the last one, which is commented).

Comment: Please write an answer, your comments made an answer collectively :) @Wikiti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's divide your question into subproblems:

#### Database & controller

Your database and controller are working properly. No need to change anything!

#### Uploaded image

You uploaded image (in params[:image]) is a `String`, instead of a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`. You should probably add the  [multipart form data](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) to your form.

#### Change filename

You can access the uploaded filename with `params[:image].original_filename`. If you want to change the filename, then you can redefine the `filename` method for your CarrierWave handler (the last one, which is commented).